# How to iterate an associative array and create multiple records with their values

Tags: php, mysql

How to iterate an associative array and create multiple records with their values.

The problem seems to be to correctly configure the variables for bind_param.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
    ["number"]=>int(1)
    ["detail"]=>string(3) "one"
  }
 [1]=>
 object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
   ["number"]=>int(2)
   ["detail"]=>string(3) "two"
 }
```

}

PHP and MYSQL

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value){
    $one = $value->number;
    $two = $value->detail;

    $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO my_tab (number, detail) VALUES (?,?)";

    if($statement = $conexion->prepare($sqlQuery)){
       $statement->bind_param("is", $one , $two);
       $statement->execute();
    }else{
    ...
    }
}
```

Expected result in my_tab:

```
number   detail
  1        one
  2        two
```

Comment: Can you explain the end-goal a bit better?

Comment: What is your problem? Do you have an error message? What is your objective? Do you want to save the array in your database? What is `$conexion`?

Comment: Thanks Samuel and Ivan. However, I found the reason for my problem that was not in PHP or mysql. I've been around this for hours and was intrigued because the script was supposed to work (and it works). Thank you for your help. I'll delete the post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why this should NOT work:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO my_tab (number, detail) VALUES (?,?)"; // no need to include this in loop - it's just a static string

if ($conexion) { // make sure this is defined
    foreach ($myArray as $key => $value){
        $one = (int)$value->number; // enforce this type as int
        $two = $value->detail;

        $statement = $conexion->prepare($sqlQuery));
        if ($statement) { 
            $statement->bind_param("is", $one , $two);
            $statement->execute();
        }else{
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. It was a problem that was not detected by all the tests I did; the problem had nothing to do with the code itself.

Comment: @josei So delete the question or it will just get downvote

Comment: @RiggsFolly i try before but because has an answer I cannot delete the question Any idea how to do that?